# ARM C Inline assembly - LDR instruction

Tags: arm, inline, inline-assembly

I am working  with inline assembly on RPI2(ARM arch) and I am using GCC for my compiler.
I want to compile and run the following part of code but I take an error, If anyone can help me or give me any help to fix the problem please. 
Here is the part of code that I need help:

```
    int main(void)
    { 
     int a;
     asm("PUSH {r0}");
     asm("PUSH {r1}");
     asm("LDR r0, =a");
     asm("MOV r1, sp");
     asm("STR r1, [r0]");
     asm("POP {r1}");
     asm("POP {r0}");
    }
```

The error that I take is about the LDR instruction. I tried to remove the '=' or instead of the LDR command to use MOV but still does not work.

Comment: That's not how you are supposed to use gcc inline assembly. Anyway, the direct cause is that `a` is a local on the stack (or even in a register) so you can't do `=a`.

Comment: Hi @Jester, can you give me any solution or alternative of how I can achieve this implementation?

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything. What are you trying to achieve? Finding the stack pointer?

Comment: Hi @Colin__s, well I know that it does not doing something special to you but for me its just a step of that I want to finally achieve. I will explain you that I want to do, maybe you can help me to fix the problem. Lets say that I have an integer array a[], the LDR r0, =a, actually stores the address of a into r0. And I want to save some registers values like SP into this array. Then through a C code by using this a[] print the a[] array values.

Comment: what if you save temps what does the compiler generated code look like (that the I assume assembler is complaining about)?

Comment: if you make a global it works.  but as Jester pointed out, as written, even if you make it a local global (static local) it doesnt have to exist as a memory location with a label, so it may not have an address to load into that register.  if you optimize your code "a" doesnt exist at all it is optimized out.  but make it a global then it gets a label and you can load the address of that label into a register.

Comment: which you could have just done in C with something=&a and not tried assembly.  (Although as a local you still end up in the same problem).

Comment: Hi @AbAbrams, I wasn't meaning to be rude, when I said it doesn't do anything I meant if it had built and you ran it it would terminate without doing anything. That was why I was asking what it was you were trying to achieve :)

Comment: Hi @Colin__s, no problem at all, I do not think that you were rude. You are right, this part of code by itself does not do so much.

Comment: I just tried to see what was happening with GNU Debugger when you execute this part of code. That I want to achieve is basically, replace the variable a with an array a[] and save the values of the registers inside. Then by calling printf print the values of the array a[]. 
 @old_timer thats why I need to use both C and assembly. By loading the base address of the int array a[] into a register. Does anyone willing to help me with this please?

Comment: pass the address to your assembly...use real assembly...or use real labels, not maybe its a label...volatile might force it to be a label for this compiler, see what you see...bottom line you are trying to do it the hard way, try something simpler.

Answer (score 1):

To access specific registers, you can use asm register variables, such as:

```c
register int sp asm("sp");
__asm__ __volatile__("" : "=r" (sp));
```